# if last char of line is [0-9]

Tags: regex, bash

This is part of a bash script
I want do something to each line that does not end with a number.
I don't know how to reference the last char of each line.

```
if lastchar != [0-9]
     awk blahblahblah
else
     awk blagblag
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the filter in `awk`:

```
 awk '/[0-9]$/{ blahblahblah } !/[0-9]$/ {blagblag}'
```

Comment: This is perfect, it compensates for my incompetence in bash scripting! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ [0-9]$ ]] || awk blah
done < file.txt
```

Or :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ [0-9]$ ]]; then
        awk blah
    else
        awk anotherblah
    fi
done < file.txt
```

`=~` is the operator for `regex` in `bash`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I've probably set it up wrong.          #!/bin/sh

for file in $*;do
        while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ [0-9]$ ]] || sed 's/$/|/'
done < file.txt

Comment: This is `bash` only, and this is your own tag dude =) So `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: #!/bin/bash

while read line; do
   [[ $line =~ [0-9]$ ]] || sed 's/$/|/'
done < file.txt
exit                                                                        I'm executing it with bash testbash.sh <testfile                          It executes but there's no output anywhere... I'm confounded.

Comment: You miss string or file argument to sed

Answer (score 1):

I like case for this under most circumstances:

```
case "$line" in
    *[0-9]) awk blahblahblah ;;
    *) awk blagblag ;;
esac
```

But if you're calling awk anyway, then the pure awk answer is probably best. (Unless you have steps you haven't shown that need to be done.)

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers have explicitly mentioned this:

> I don't know how to reference the last char of each line.

A [`regular expression`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to match the pattern: `line ends in number` can be constructed using `[0-9]$` [match anything between `0` and `9`, followed by the `end-of-line` (`$` is the `end-of-line anchor`)].

The anchor for `beginning-of-line` is `^`.